# Render "outlined" input when using react-text-mask with Material-UI inputs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm unable to figure out how to render outlined input type(one of the standard Material-UI input styles when used with text mask).

I copied the code sample from here: https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/
But it only gives a sample for regular(underlined) input but nothing for outlined.

This is what i'm trying to do but it doesnt work:

```
const ExpirationMask = props => {
  const { inputRef, ...other } = props

  return <MaskedInput
      {...other}
      ref={ref => {inputRef(ref ? ref.inputElement : null)}}
      mask={[/\d/, /\d/,'/' ,/\d/, /\d/]}
      placeholderChar={'\u2000'}
    />
}

<FormControl
  variant='outlined'                         //this doesnt work
  fullWidth
>
<InputLabel>Expiration</InputLabel>
<Input
  value={ccExpiration}
  onChange={(e, v) => setCCExpiration(e.target.value)}
  placeholder='MM/YY'
  variant='outlined'                         //this doesnt work either
  inputComponent={ExpirationMask}
/>
</FormControl>
```

Comment: AFAIK variant is a property of <TextField/> component and you used it for input.. input does not have variant property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution for it. I didn't realize that `TextField` is just a wrapper for the `Input`.

There is also another wrapper for the Input which is called `OutlinedInput`. So this was exactly what I ended up using:

```
<FormControl
  fullWidth
  margin='dense'
>
<InputLabel
  classes={{ root: classes.expInputRoot }}
  error={ccExpiration.trim().length < 5}
  color='primary'>
  Expiration
</InputLabel>
<OutlinedInput
  value={ccExpiration}
  onChange={(e, v) => setCCExpiration(e.target.value)}
  label="Expiration"
  placeholder='MM/YY'
  error={ccExpiration.trim().length < 5}
  inputComponent={ExpirationMask}
/>
</FormControl>
```

In doing so i encountered another problem however with an `InputLabel` that wasn't aligning properly(not sure if it is a bug or what), so i ended up manually changing styles for it like this:

```
 expInputRoot: {
    margin:'-8px 0 0 14px'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to imporve the answer a bit, the Ourlined Input has a label property which will help create a legend element to make room in the border for the label. Should look like this:

```js
<FormControl
  fullWidth
  margin='dense'
>
<InputLabel
  error={ccExpiration.trim().length < 5}
  color='primary'>
  Expiration
</InputLabel>
<OutlinedInput
  value={ccExpiration}
  onChange={(e, v) => setCCExpiration(e.target.value)}
  label="Expiration"
  placeholder='MM/YY'
  error={ccExpiration.trim().length < 5}
  inputComponent={ExpirationMask}
  label='Expiration'
/>
</FormControl>
```